# document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML kills the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing on a site built with ServiceNow and Angular.js.  page seems to works fine until I make `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;` After replacing the body with itself, all `Buttons/onClicks` or searches stopped being responsive.. 
Anyone knows what might be going on underneath? How to observe the difference between old body and new body?

Comment: why would you do that? But using innerHTML to copy does not maintain anything. You do not keep form values, event listeners, etc.

Comment: @epascarello There was an issue printing the original page. It can only print one single page instead of the entire document. Strangely if I replace the body with one div, then do the window.print(), the entire div can be printed. Now I want to switch back to the original content.

Comment: Maybe a print stylesheet is an option and figure out what in the CSS prevents it from printing correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kills your listeners if they were added at runtime because the scope can't be serialized.